# Android Time Ranking

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am currently having a problem with the time ranking on my android application. I am working with the `sqlite` database that will store the time the user **finished** solving the problem. I will use that `sqlite` database later to display the **rankings** of the user that played the game.

For example, the player finished the puzzle for about 1:25 *(1 minute and 25 seconds)*, the app will store `1:25` on the sqlite database. But I'm having a problem on doing that.

- I can store it on the `sqlite` as a `string` but I can't use `ORDER
  BY`.
- I tried storing it as an `int` but output says: *invalid `int`*
- I tried storing it as a `string` while removing the colon (**:**) but the database on returns "125".

**My question is**: **What is the best way to store that specific time value on `sqlite` databases?**

I read [this http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) documentation about the Time and Date Functions but it seems it can't be applied on custom time. It only applies on either the *date now or current time*. Please I need help on this. I'm an android and sqlite amateur. This project is my thesis for this sem.

Any comments and suggestions are accepted. Thanks in advance!

By the way, this is the code that retrieves all the data on my sqlite. It's a testing program, to test if my codes/to modify codes and see if they are working.

```
try {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_OUTLET + " WHERE category LIKE '" + cat + "' ORDER BY category ASC";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                // Read columns data
                int outlet_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("outlet_id"));
                String outlet_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("outlet_name"));
                String outlet_type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("outlet_type"));
                String category = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("category"));


                // dara rows
                TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
                row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                String[] colText = {outlet_name, outlet_type, category};
                for (String text : colText) {
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    tv.setTextSize(16);
                    tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                    tv.setText(text);
                    row.addView(tv);
                }
                tableLayout.addView(row);

            }

        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
        // End the transaction.
        db.close();
        // Close database
    }
}
```

Comment: You can convert the whole thing into seconds and store it.

Comment: @ShreyashSSarnayak Do i need to convert it first and store it on the database or store it first and convert it later when retrieving the data?

Comment: "I tried storing it as an int but output says: invalid int", there must have been a flaw with this, can you expand?

Comment: @petey for example i stored 01:25 on the database. I used Integer.parseInt("01:25"). The error says: Invalid `int`: 01:25. I think it's because of the colon(:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1:25` convert this to seconds only.

That is `1 * 60 + 25 = 85`. So store `85`.

Every time you want to store it do this. And you can do the reverse on restoring.

In example,

```
sec = 85 % 60 = 25
min = 85 / 60 = 1
```

You will get `1:25`

Comment: I think this answer is much clearer than the others. Thanks for this. Gonna try this.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion of @ShreyashSSarnayak I managed to fix this problem.

This is the resulting code:

```
try {
            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_OUTLET + " WHERE category LIKE '" + cat + "' ORDER BY outlet_type ASC";
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                    // Read columns data
                    int outlet_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("outlet_id"));
                    String outlet_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("outlet_name"));
                    int outlet_type = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("outlet_type")));
                    String category = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("category"));


                    // dara rows
                    TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
                    row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    int m, s;
                    s = outlet_type % 60;
                    m = outlet_type / 60;

                    String[] colText = {outlet_name, String.format("%02d:%02d", m, s), category};
                    for (String text : colText) {
                        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                        tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        tv.setTextSize(16);
                        tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                        tv.setText(text);
                        row.addView(tv);
                    }
                    tableLayout.addView(row);

                }

            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
            // End the transaction.
            db.close();
            // Close database
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to convert your time to seconds and store it as `integer`.

Comment: Should I convert it first? Or convert it when retrieving the data?

Comment: Convert your time before saving it to database. Later you will be able to retrieve time in seconds from database

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use **INTEGER** as database type instead. Check [here](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) available types. Then you need to convert the INTEGER value to time format using standard java clases or any other if you like.

Using INTEGER you will be also able to sort them easily.